# web reference not working when deployed live

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-reference

I used a webreference in my mvc project. It is working properly for my project locally but i am getting the following error when i deployed my project in live.

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:

> A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not
>   properly respond after a period of time, or established connection
>   failed because connected host has failed to respond 46.xxx.xxx.xxx:80

Please help me solve this.

Comment: It's not deployed correctly, check the server logs for errors.

Comment: Can you access the server that the web service is on from your live server?

Comment: Yes i can access the server, my web reference and project are deployed on same server.